Clicking left physical button on Thinkpad trackpoint registers duplicate clicks in Firefox
I have a ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 9. When I use the left physical/hardware button beneath the keyboard it works fine except in the rendered content area of Firefox where it often registers a duplicate click.
For example, if I click the Stack Exchange icon at the top right of the Ask Ubuntu interface, the community dropdown with open then immediately close.
Tapping on the touch pad works fine - just a single click is registered. Using the button in other apps, and in the Firefox chrome also works fine.
xinput seems to show only one event is fired when I click the button. Three clicks shows:
button press   1 
button release 1 
button press   1 
button release 1 
button press   1 
button release 1 

What could cause this behaviour in Firefox only? Is it something to do with some underlying framework that Firefox uses for its rendered area? I can't see anything in about:config to adjust this.
